# Instant push message from Lambda to Web Host?

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

What is good approach to send a message to Laravel via AWS Lambda in real time (or near real time)?

I could add a message in the SQS via Lambda and Laravel will read the SQS but that will require polling to read from SQS queue every minute or so..

Another approach is to send a message to Laravel via API but what if laravel host in down, then we are screwed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how we handled it with Laravel,

> Kinesis Data Streams --> (Kinesis Trigger) Lambda --> Laravel

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-kinesis.html

If Laravel is down, then throw an exception in Lambda and the message will be retried back to Lambda to try again.

This will be tried until the message in the Kinesis lives for its life time. If you set the storage time to 7 days, it will be retried for 7 days, before the data disappears from the kinesis stream.

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: Is it possible to see the messages in the Kinesis if Lambda failed? So that I will know how many messages has not been processed.

Comment: You can go back in time with Kinesis. If your lambda fails to process the pointer to kinesis stream will not move from there until the data gets expired. There is no UI to peek into the messages, you can programmatically pull down the messages again or ask the lambda to process from begining.

Comment: What is Kinesis alternative?

Comment: I don't see any duplicate service or similar alternatives within AWS. Most of the services are unique. You can use SQS, but it will be very slow and involves transaction and not flexible like kinesis.